# Spring Boot auto refresh cache

Tags: caching, spring-boot

does spring boot support cache auto refresh ? or refresh / reprime the cache on demand.

How to implement such features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default Spring Boot cache implementation uses ConcurrentHashMap and does not seem to support auto refresh.

However,  Spring Boot supports other cache implementations, e.g. ehCache, which can evict cache entries based on configured parameters.

Comment: I am currently implementing with ehCache3. all works well.  I am porting some services from .NET to Java/Spring-boot, and want to see if Spring-boot offers the same cache API as .NET has.   .NET cache, can be primed, re-primed while ehCache can evict, but ehCache would not refresh the cache until the next Cache-able method is called.  Also, in .NET, it can automatically refresh the cache itself which I also do not see in ehCache.  I am relatively new in Spring-boot.  I may have missed something.